# How to prevent Game Center from altering icon badge?

Tags: ios, game-center, badge

I have an iOS app that until a few months ago used Game Center for turn-based multiplayer functionality. It now uses a custom-built server instead, and I have turned off Game Center for the last versions of the app in iTunes Connect. However, each time I start some other app that *does* use Game Center, the system removes whatever badge number I have on my icon. As if my app was still Game Center enabled and had no current matches where there was my turn to act.

Is there any way to prevent this lingering Game Center behavior, i.e. to tell Game Center to mind its own business and not to mess with the icon badge anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Forgetting to disable Game Center on your app on the iTunes Connect back end can cause this issue